# Connection of external crystal oscillators for FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am designing a Triple modular redundancy processor (TMR) system to synthesize in an Altera DE10lite FPGA Board. Its purpose is to demonstrate reliability of computation under the present of various faults. I need advice on how to connect three external crystal oscillators (instead of the on board crystal), with same ratings to drive the three processors inside the FPGA.I will be using a synchronization voting scheme to sync all three signals. Can this task be done?
[Clock distribution triplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJMMH.jpg)

I have read the following relevant links that describe using PLL's is this the correct way?
https://www.altera.com/documentation/mcn1395213337540.html#mcn1395213788377

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no code provided or any showing of an attempt to solve it by the questioner.

Comment: The reason for this is that it is a complex procedure, i believe, and haven't done this before in any of my designs

Comment: This is a question for [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Oh sorry, should I transfer it to Electrical Engineering and delete from here?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's unlikely to work.

If you run each soft CPU with a separate crystal, they will drift out of synchronization due to slight variations in frequency between the crystals.

If you try to use a majority voting scheme to create a single clock signal from three input clocks, you'll end up with a very weird, irregular clock signal which will probably cause faults in the logic driven by it.

Use one clock source at a time. If you're convinced you need to resist failures of an external clock, consider implementing some way to detect a failure in the current clock and switch to another one. (Keep in mind that this logic will need to still work without a functional clock… which may be difficult.)

Comment: ...Unless you implement a periodic synchronization scheme -something the asker wants to do-. Asynchronous redundancy systems have been used very often in high-risk high-impact systems (like nuclear power plants). You always need some form of synchronization to be able to do a majority vote.

Comment: Synchronization voting is a feedback procedure to deal with drifting and keep the three signals in the same period of execution. The voting will compensate for the slowest signal if there is significant drift in a 2/3 manner.